# Scoreloop hangs on "connecting" when displaying higscores on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, scoreloop

I try to implement Scoreloop in libgdx. I used some tutorials [here](http://moldedbits.com/blog/2012/02/26/integrating-scoreloop-with-libgdx/) and [here](http://rebigames.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/8-steps-for-intergrating-scoreloop-with-libgdx/). When I run the game and try to show the higscores with showscoreLoop() I have to accept TOS first. After pressing "enable" (accept) window with "Connecting, please wait" show and nothing happens...When I minimize the app and start it again, I get the nullexception when I try to access the highscores again.

Any help here? I'm really desperate as there is almost no support for Scoreloop..

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't answer your question directly, but it might end up saving you a good bit of time in the long run.

We've had some good success with LibGDX projects using Swarm (aka [SwarmConnect](http://swarmconnect.com)) for leaderboards in Android games.  Integration is pretty straight forward as long as you initialize at the end of onResume() and remember to make calls to Swarm.setActive() and Swarm.setInactive() in the right places.  It's documented pretty well though.

If you go to the [LibGDX forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum) and do a quick search for SwarmConnect, you'll find plenty of links to threads that can help :).  Cheers!